# How do I stick one div to the upper right corner?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

There is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_blond97/2hfkcyt4/).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.sticked {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  <div class="content">Content 4</div>
  <div class="content">Content 5</div>
  <div class="content">Content 6</div>
  <div class="content">Content 7</div>
  <div class="content">Content 8</div>
  <div class="content">Content 9</div>
  <div class="content">Content 10</div>
  <div class="content">Content 11</div>
  <div class="content">Content 12</div>
  <div class="content">Content 13</div>
  <div class="content">Content 14</div>
  <div class="content">Content 15</div>

  <div class="content sticked">Div in Upper Right Corner</div>
</div>
```

I need the "sticked" element always to be placed in the place of top right elements ("Content 6" and "Content 12" on the picture below)

[image]

Or at the place of "Content 3" and "Content 6" on the picture below

[image]

How do I stick one of the flex divs to right upper corner?

Comment: Just remove it from the flex container?

Comment: Quite simply...with your current structure & flexbox, you can't.

Comment: ...and I don't believe there is *any* layout method which will let you do that. **Maybe** CSS-Grid but I'd have to think about that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with CSS grid:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(100px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows:100px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.sticked {
  grid-column:-2; /* last column */
  grid-row:1/span 2;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  <div class="content">Content 4</div>
  <div class="content">Content 5</div>
  <div class="content">Content 6</div>
  <div class="content">Content 7</div>
  <div class="content">Content 8</div>
  <div class="content">Content 9</div>
  <div class="content">Content 10</div>
  <div class="content">Content 11</div>
  <div class="content">Content 12</div>
  <div class="content">Content 13</div>
  <div class="content">Content 14</div>
  <div class="content">Content 15</div> 
  <div class="content">Content 16</div>
  <div class="content">Content 17</div>
  <div class="content">Content 18</div>
  <div class="content">Content 19</div> 
  <div class="content">Content 20</div>
  <div class="content">Content 21</div>
  <div class="content">Content 22</div>
  <div class="content">Content 23</div> 

  <div  class="content sticked">Div in Upper Right Corner</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D yes it does (I added more items). it's also responsive

Comment: Nice...I was working on this and you beat me to it.